# Homotopy groups of $\Omega$-spectra

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\mathbf{E}=\{ (E_n, \sigma_n) : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ be a $\Omega$- spectrum, that is that the adjoints of the structure maps are weak homotopy equivalences. Is the following true for the homotopy groups?

$$
\pi_i(\mathbf{E})= \begin{cases}
\pi_i(E_0), & i\ge 0 \\
\pi_0(E_n),  & i \le 0
\end{cases}
$$
I've seen a paper where homotopy groups were definied exactly like this. But I have never seen a paper where homotopy groups were defined by the inductive limit construction and then this remark was made. I think it is worth mentioning. If it is true, does that mean that for an infinite loop space $E_0$ the $0^{th}$-homotopy (group) has a group structure?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes to both questions. Actually, an $H$-group (operations only defined up to homotopy and only satisfy standard identities up to homotopy) already has the structure of a group on $\pi_0$.

Comment: Where is the $n$ in your formulae for the homotopy groups coming from?